# Is there a way to access a model's fields in liquid templates?

Tags: liquid, locomotivecms

I'm currently playing with Locomotive CMS, and have created a Model via the control panel. Within that model I have created a select menu called "category". It looks something like this in yaml :

```
- category:
    label: Category
    type: select
    required: true
    select_options: *70168253718360
```

Basically I want to loop over all of the various entries in this model, but sort them by category, and insert a header for each category... I've done a bunch of reading in the [locomotivecms documentation](http://doc.locomotivecms.com/references), but somehow this escapes me. I could see creating a model for each, but that would quickly become a mess as I'm going to have quite a few, and of course, is repeating a task over and over a lot.

Does anyone know if this is somehow possible? Or if there's a better way to go about this? Thank you very  much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two ways you could do this. The first would be simpler, you would add a select field to the model. Under the presentation section of edit model page, you will be able to select a group by. Select your new field and then when you loop over the model you will be passed a hash instead of an array. The second option is to create a second model and create a belongs to/has many relationship between your first model and the new one.